# Parse JS SDK login does not keep the current user info using AngularJs ui routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

Here is my module config and run:

```
angular.module('FXBApp', [
'ui.bootstrap'
,'ui.router'
,'oc.lazyLoad'
,'parse-angular'
]).
config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', '$ocLazyLoadProvider',
function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider,$ocLazyLoadProvider) {


  $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
                                debug:false,
                                events:true
                              });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

  $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "views/login/login.html",
        controller:'LoginCtrl',
        resolve:{
          loadMyFiles:function($ocLazyLoad){
            return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              name: 'FXBApp',
              files: ['scripts/controllers/login.js']
            })
          }
        }
      })
      .state('dashboard', {
          url: "/dashboard",
          templateUrl: "views/dashboard/main.html",
          controller:'DashboardMainCtrl',
          resolve:{
              loadMyFiles:function($ocLazyLoad){
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      name: 'FXBApp',
                      files: [
                                'views/dashboard/dashboard.main.js'
                                ,'views/dashboard/ribbon.js'
                                ,'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar.js'

                      ]
                  })
              }
          }
      })
      .state('dashboard.home', {
          url: "/dashboard/home",
          templateUrl: "views/dashboard/home.html",
          controller:'DashboardHomeCtrl',
          resolve:{
              loadMyFiles:function($ocLazyLoad){
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      name: 'FXBApp',
                      files: [
                                'scripts/controllers/dashboard.home.js'
                                ,'scripts/services/authentication.js'
                                ,'scripts/directives/stats/stats.js'
                                ,'scripts/services/dbstats.js'
                      ]
                  })
              }
          }
      })
run(['$rootScope','$state', function ($rootScope,$state) {
Parse.initialize("$$$$$$$", "######");
$rootScope.sessionUser ={};

$rootScope.isLoggedIn = function () {
    if (!Parse.User.current()) $state.go('login');
};

$rootScope.logOut = function () {
    Parse.User.logOut()
};
$rootScope.authUser = function (usr, pwd) {
    //TODO: assure user is active and e-mail is verified
    return Parse.User.logIn(usr,pwd).then(function (user) {
        var qr = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
        qr.equalTo('users', Parse.User.current().id);
        return qr.first().then(function (e) {
            try {
                if (e.getName() != 'admin' && e.getName() != 'team_leader') {
                    return {err: true, userId: user.id, msg: 'User does not have permission to access'}
                } else {
                    $rootScope.sessionUser = user;
                    return {err: false, userId: user.id}
                }
            } catch (e) {
                return {err: true, userId: user.id, msg: 'User not assigned to any role--'+e}
            }
        }, function (e){
            return {err: true, userId: user.id, msg:e.msg}

        });

    }, function (error) {
        return {err:true,msg:error.message}
    });
};

$rootScope.isLoggedIn()
}]);
```

As you can see I am using ui router as well as lazy loading to manage the app performance properly.

As soon as the login sequence initiated form the login controller using `$rootScope.authUser($scope.usr,$scope.pwd)`, if I use `then()` close attached to this call I can console `Parse.User.current()` which shows the current user.

Routing works fine after login, the tricky part is when I tried to fetch  data from parse.com class allowed for the user after the successful login; it always gives 403 error. Investigating the cause, I found that `Parse.User.current()` is returning null while `$rootScope.sessionUser` holds the right reference to the logged in user.

I tried using 'Parse.Session.getSessionToken' and the error was 'no current user'. I tried using `Parse.User.become($rootScope.sessionUsr.getSessionToken())` but things get worse as now I am getting the invalid session token error and have to go to the chrome console to delete parse sdk objects from storage.

Any idea what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Was a long journey till I discovered the root cause of my problem. It was not related to Parse SDK nor angular. It was related to a directive that shows the logout button (not shown in the problem post) this directive was calling `doLogOut` $scope function which was in turn triggering the sign-out sequence using `Parse.User.logOut()`.

Every time this directive loads after the login the function `doLogOut` was being called resulting in clearing the session in Parse and causing system to be unable to do any restricted action on the db.

The reason that the `doLogout` was being triggered instead of waiting 'ng-click' event was simply that angular is evaluating $scope every time it loads. This means it will evaluate 'doLogOut' on load and not waiting for an event. Changing 'doLogOut' to 'doLogOut()` fixed the problem.

A stupid mistake created a lot of complexity by the end.